# PDF of $Y = \frac{X_1 + X_2 + ... + X_n}{n}$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, convolution, central-limit-theorem, cumulative-distribution-functions

In CLT we have $$Y = \frac{X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_n}{n}$$ where $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ are statistically independent and identically distributed (i.i.d.) random variables. Is there a way to find the PDF of $Y$ for any $n$?

I tried to calculate the PDF of $Z = X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_n$ and I reached

$$f_Z(z) = f_{x_1}(z) * f_{x_2}(z) * \cdots * f_{x_n}(z)$$

but I couldn't find the PDF where the sum of $X_i$'s are divided by $n$ and that's why I asked this question.

I calculated the characteristic function of $Y$:

$$\Phi_Y(w) = \Phi_{X_1} \left(\frac{w}{n}\right) \cdot \Phi_{X_2}\left(\frac{w}{n}\right) \cdots \Phi_{X_n}\left(\frac{w}{n}\right)$$

but I don't know how to use this to find its PDF.

Comment: What does $*$ denote here? Product would not be okay. On LHS if find argument $z$ but on RHS I find argument $x$, so things are wrong.

Comment: * is convolution not product

Comment: Okay, but where is argument $z$ on RHS? If you can find the characteristic function then look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)#Inversion_formulae) for finding PDF.

Comment: The PDF of $Z$ is right. Now you just need to answer this question: $A$ is an RV with PDF $f(x)$, what is the PDF of the random variable $B = \lambda A$ where $\lambda$ is a constant.

Comment: thanks drhab. I edited it

Comment: Why not convolve the PDF with itself $n$ times?

Comment: Actually the notation should be $(f*f*\cdots*f)(z)$.

Comment: Are you familiar with the theorem proven [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2462286/proof-of-inversion-theorem-for-characteristic-functions)?

Comment: @drhab yes but because $X_i's$ are i.i.d so we can write $(f*f*...*f)(z)=f(z)*f(z)*...*f(z)$

Comment: @SeanEberhard Could you please explain more

Comment: I was trying to provoke you into realizing that if $A$ has PDF $f(x)$ then $B = \lambda A$ has PDF $f(x / \lambda) / \lambda$. Hence your sample mean $Y$ has PDF $n(f*\cdots*f)(ny)$ (though, incidentally, if this is related to CLT then you may want to normalize by $n^{1/2}$ rather than $n$).

Answer (score 1):

You can always think of the probability (density) to measure $Y$ as all the possible probabilities summed up for $X_1,...,X_n$ under the constraint that $Y=g(X_1,...,X_n)$ (Here you have $g(X_1,...,X_n)=\frac{X_1+...+X_n}{n}$). Mathematically speaking you are looking for a PDF for Y s.t. the probability to measure $y$ is given by
$$f_Y(y) \, {\rm d}y = \int {\rm d}x_1 \dots \int {\rm d}x_n \left(\delta(y-g(x_1,...,x_n)) \, {\rm d}y \right)\, f_{X_1}(x_1)\dots f_{X_n}(x_n)$$
where $\delta$ is the delta function. You can think of $\delta(y-g(x_1,...,x_n)) \, {\rm d}y$ being $1$ if the constraint is fulfilled and $0$ (giving no contribution) if not. In your case you can eliminate one x-integration using the $\delta$-function and end up with some similar sort of convolution.

Comment: thanks. but as I said I want to use characteristic functions to find $f_Y(y)$

Comment: Given your characteristic function, don't you just have to calc. the Fouriertransform of it? $$f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty  \Phi_Y(w) e^{-iyw} \, {\rm d}w$$